# CiviCRM installed, but configuration screen not as described

Tags: wordpress, configuration

after installing the CiviCRM plugin, I read:"CiviCRM is almost ready. You must configure CiviCRM for it to work."
If I click the link to configure, or do the following:
"Then go to Settings > CiviCRM Installer: http:///wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install You should see the CiviCRM Installer screen."

then I see only the left and top menu, with 'Settings>CiviCRM Installer' highlit, and a reminder to update Wordpress, but nothing else.

I'm installing CiviCRM 4.6.16 in Wordpress 4.5

I looked for but didn't find .../civicrm.settings.php .

Dec 2016 - I have now re-installed MySql, PHP & wordpress and again activated CiviCRM, but face the same situation on trying to install CiviCRM: a grey blank center of the screen, with wordpress options on top and left edge.

This LAMP stack is on Ubuntu server 16.0.1.

Comment: Could you clarify your question with screenshots and more specifically describe the steps you have taken?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/RFaiuCk

Comment: Thanks for responding Coleman, 
Here's a before-clicking-screenshot: http://imgur.com/caRu3zT
Here's an after-clicking-one:
http://imgur.com/RFaiuCk
I'll try to be more specific, but my memory is so short I forget exactly what I did. I did try to reload the civiCRM plugin, this time by wget, which is why there are two civicrm plugins in the before screenshot. This didn't solve things.
I also loosened permissions for some folders/directories.

Comment: Well, I'm now seeking professional help (for the CiviCRM installation) through GreenLeaf, in nearby Guilford CT.

Comment: I guess there's no one home at Greenleaf - I'm trying to get php error logging working, but there's no /var/www/php* , curiously enough.

Comment: /var/log/apache2 contains multiples of this:

Comment: /var/log/apache2 contains multiples of this: 
[date time] [:error] [pid 1323] [client 192.168.1.10:59033] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting identifier (t_STRING) or '(' in /home/GRP/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(207) : eval()'d code on line 1, referer: http://192.168.1.254/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s

Comment: I've reinstalled wordpress  parallel to the above installation, installed CiviCRM and activated it, and am attempting to configure the CiviCRM plugin. but again get this blank-center Wordpress screen: http://imgur.com/WoAcp3Y
I see no php errors after turning on php error logging through index.php.

Comment: The WP installation's error log again reads ...PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or '(' in home/boston/wp--content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/dataObject.php(207) : eval()'d code on line 1, referer: http://(website)/wp-admin/index.php

Comment: I have now re-installed wordpress and again activated CiviCRM, but face the same situation on trying to install CiviCRM: a grey blank center of the screen, with wordpress options on top and left edges.

Comment: You don't mention which Linux distribution you're using. It would be useful to know so we can direct you to the correct location of the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Install civicrm 4.7, not 4.6...LTS

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer.  Any idea why it works with CiviCRM 4.7 but not 4.6?